# How to get cell value in excel workbook project using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

I have an excel 2010 c# project, how do I get the value from a cell? I've found a lot of solutions for opening an excel file and then getting the value. But in this case the file is part of the soultion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the following is what I am after:

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Range show = Globals.Sheet8.Range["A6"];
    MessageBox.Show(show.Text);
}
```

Credit to http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-office-excel-programming-using-vsto for showing the way

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with excel and your file is in the newer xlsx format, you might want to take a look at [ExtremeML](http://www.extrememl.com). It's a great library which can help you read/write excel files without having to use Office automation, thus increasing your program performance.

Comment: Thanks for the link J, this isn't quite what I am after but looks like a handy tool to have for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the file is part of your Visual Studio solution, you still have to do the usual file IO routine, e.g. open it, read it, then close it.  Making it part of your solution mainly just means the file is packaged with your binaries when you compile, and you can select various options for what to do with the file at compile time.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been a bit busy this week. What would be the best way to go about achieving this? I want to get the values of cells from a spreadsheet when it is saved as a new document and to be seamless i.e no third party app, embedded within the excel document.

Comment: @Beuy: There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to open and read an Excel file, for example: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm

However, if you want your program to notice when the Excel file has been edited externally by another program or user, that's a lot more complicated.  The simplest way to deal with that is to require the user to click a "Refresh data from Excel spreadsheet" button in your program's UI or something similar to trigger a fresh read of the file.

Comment: ah ha! Looks like I'm not so crazy after all ;) 
private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Excel.Range show = Globals.Sheet8.Range["A6"];
  MessageBox.Show(show.Text);
}

Working for me!

Answer (score 0):

make a cursor string...

example:

```
string cusrsor = "d5";
ExcelName.get_range(cursor,cursor).Value2 = "you put here value";

//more codes
//more codes
more codes

if you want to get the cell from this file..
just use the cursor or pointer to put you there...
```

Comment: Sorry Gian this didn't work, I think DGH may be onto something with having to open the file for IO access regardless of it being part of the VS solution.